# How do I figure out the disc numbers in a release result from py-musicbrainz2?

Tags: python, musicbrainz

The documentation for the Python musicbrainz2 library tells me that this is how I search for a release by disc id:

```
>>> import musicbrainz2.webservice as ws
>>> q = ws.Query()
>>> filter = ws.ReleaseFilter(discId='8jJklE258v6GofIqDIrE.c5ejBE-')
>>> results = q.getReleases(filter=filter)
>>> results[0].score
100
>>> results[0].release.title
u'Under the Pink'
```

But for a double CD I get the same release (as it should be) but different tracks when I search for the disc ID for the two CDs. This is also as it should be, but I don't see a way to get the disc number from the result of the query. Is it there somewhere? I think it is there in the XML, as a "medium".

Comment: Like you say it seems that the `count` attribute of the `<medium-list>` tag is the number of discs in the release. However I can't also find it anywhere in the module API and a quick grep of the source code doesn't find any reference to that tag either.

Comment: Time for a patch then. But I'm not sure I can find the time right now.

Answer (score 3):

The [musicbrainz2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-musicbrainz2/0.7.2) package, despite its name, seems to support only the deprecated version 1 of the web service's schema, which, as far as I could find, does not provide media information.

The solution seems to be to use instead, the [musicbrainzngs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/musicbrainzngs/0.2) package, which supports the MusicBrainz NGS web service (version 2). Then you just need to do something like the following (based on the example provided in the package's source):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import musicbrainzngs
>>> musicbrainzngs.set_useragent("application", "0.01", "http://example.com")
>>> pprint(musicbrainzngs.get_release_by_id("e94757ff-2655-4690-b369-4012beba6114",["media"]))
{'release': {'barcode': '9421021463277',
             'country': 'NZ',
             'date': '2008-07-04',
             'id': 'e94757ff-2655-4690-b369-4012beba6114',
             'medium-list': [{'format': 'CD',
                              'position': '1',
                              'track-list': []}],
             'quality': 'normal',
             'status': 'Official',
             'text-representation': {'language': 'eng', 'script': 'Latn'},
             'title': 'Affordable Pop Music'}}
```

And voilà: `medium-list` information available!